# Bootstrap 3 nav without pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a nav in my header.
The HTML currently looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right logon-nav">
    <li><a href="/Profile">Username</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Settings">Settings</a></li>      
    <li><a href="/Account/LogOff">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using Bootstrap this looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3WGt6/

Now I want to achieve a similar result but without the pills (i.e. just underline). I know I could do this in CSS but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Think you need to change the CSS.

Comment: cleaner solution? what's wrong with overriding some styles? I guess the only other option is using `list-inline` instead of `nav` but you don't get the correct spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/3WGt6/1/

Comment: have you tried removing nav-pills class? and using navbar-nav pull-right?

Comment: CSS only, without bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use .nav or .nav-pills. Instead, drop a .list-inline on the `ul`: http://jsfiddle.net/3WGt6/2/